# How can one call the superclass method from a subclass method and return control to the subclass method for an S4 class?

Tags: r, r-s4

If I make two classes like such:

```
setClass("SuperClass", slots=c(a="character"), prototype=list(a="A"))
setClass("SubClass", slots=c(b="character"), prototype=list(b="B"), contains="SuperClass")
```

and some method like such:

```
setGeneric("foobar", function(x) standardGeneric("foobar"))
setMethod("foobar", "SuperClass", function(x) { cat(x@a, "\n", sep="") })
```

How can I write a method `foobar` for the class `SubClass` that can call the `foobar` method for `SuperClass` and then do some other `SubClass` specific computation?

The method could look something like this:

```
setMethod("foobar", "SubClass", function(x) {
        # call SuperClass's foobar
        cat(x@b, "\n", sep="")
})
```

and then if I do this:

```
x <- new("SubClass")
foobar(x)
```

it should print

```
"A"
"B"
```

Of course this is a trivial use-case that can be solved by other approaches, but I think it captures that spirit of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `callNextMethod`:

```r
setMethod("foobar", "SubClass", function(x) {
        callNextMethod()
        cat(x@b, "\n", sep="")
})
x <- new("SubClass")
foobar(x)
# A
# B
```